# How to avoid a "java.util.NoSuchElementException" crashing my program

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

TL;DR-- how to get a java.util.NoSuchElementException to return a null instead of error and crash the program.

I was writing a program that is supposed to read a series of ints from a text file. In the program the amount of ints will vary each time I run it. I have written a piece of code that will read ints and I want to know how to make the java.util.NoSuchElementException not crash my program and instead return a null.
 The code I have writen is as follows

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(new File("newestcode.txt"));
    Integer[] digits = new Integer[100];
    int h = 0;
    while(true){
        digits[h] = Input.nextInt();
        h++;
        System.out.println(digits[h]);
    }
}
```

in case you are curious, the program I am to be writing is a sort of decryption engine for a bad encryption engine I wrote the other day

Comment: Have you heard of try-catch?

Comment: Please follow the naming conventions for fields, use camelCase. Because your field `Input` could look like a class, using a static method.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    digits[h] = Input.nextInt();
    h++;
    System.out.println(digits[h]);
}catch (NoSuchElementException e){
    break;
}
```

Comment: If you need an explanation on how it works just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're not sure about amount of ints in your file, don't try to store them into fixed-size array. Use ArrayList instead.

Also don't use endless loop `while(true)` but consider using `Input.hasNext()` to check if there still is something to read from file.

And one more. You're trying to print value after increment. This means that you're adding element on 0 position but trying to read it from 1 position. Make increment on the end of the loop.

```
Scanner Input = new Scanner(new File("newestcode.txt"));
List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
int h = 0;
while(Input.hasNetxt()){
    digits.add(h, Input.nextInt());
    System.out.println(digits.get(h));
    h++;
}
```

Comment: Minor typo, it's `Input.hasNext()` not `Input.hasNetxt()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the input.hasNext() method to check whether the input has any more 'int' before using it.
In order to support any length of int elements, you cannot set the array to a fixed length of 100, you need to use an ArrayList to add elements dynamically.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("./newestcode.txt"));
List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
int h = 0;
while (input.hasNext()) {
    digits.add(h, input.nextInt());
    System.out.println(digits.get(h));
    h++;
}
```

Note: You need to print digits[h] before increasing the h.